# O arquivo está travado - Excel e VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba

Tenho uma planilha do excel com userform para controle de uma base de dados que também é em excel, essa base de dados por ter muitos acessos é compartilhada, porém hoje vi que o VBA não se dá muito bem com arquivos compartilhados, ao salvar o arquivo eu recebi o erro de que o arquivo está travado. O comando foi esse:

```
Private Sub Sair_Click()

    Unload Me

    Workbooks("database.xlsx").Close savechanges:=True
    Workbooks("Controle de Contratos-2020.xlsb").Close savechanges:=True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True 'reativar alertas


End Sub
```

A planilha compartilhada é essa database.

Answer (score 2):

Excel não é um software feito para ser utilizado como banco de dados. Possui vários problemas com compartilhamento, não pode ser acessado por dois clientes ao mesmo tempo, pode gerar inúmeros conflitos na hora de salvar os arquivos. Minha sugestão é migrar essa planilha para um banco em Access pois será o que você terá um melhor suporte para continuar usando o vba.

Comment: Alex, eu sou totalmente leigo em banco de dados, há como gravar os dados lá sem precisar usar muito SQL? Pois o meu fraco realmente é a parte do SQL

Comment: Você já trabalhou com Access? é um Software do pacote Office destinado especificamente para bancos de dados, e por ser do Office assim como o excel é o mais indicado para continuar trabalhando com VBA. Procurei rapidamente aqui e encontrei alguns exemplos que podem te ajudar: [aqui](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XLC8Kzn1YcY), [aqui](https://www.guiadoexcel.com.br/cadastro-em-excel-com-banco-de-dados-access-sql/) [aqui](https://diarioexcel.com.br/2017/07/12/excel-access/). Boa sorte!